Как в woocommerce включить возможность продавать товар в определенные дни недели?
В общем, стоит задача продавать определённую категорию товара (или один товар) в определённые дни недели. То есть чтобы товар постоянно висел в каталоге (возможно в статусе "Нет в наличии"), но купить его можно было только в понедельник, среду и пятницу.
Я смог найти WPC Product Timer for WooCommerce — плагин, который выполняет эту задачу. Но он работает только при условии, что выбран только один день недели. Если выбрать два и больше, то правило перестаёт работать (хотя такая возможность заложена в функционал).
Какие альтернативы есть для достижения нужного результата?

Так продавать или покупать? Палю тему: ПРОДАВАЙТЕ когда хотите (хоть раз в году), не запрещая ЗАКАЗЫВАТЬ когда угодно.

Задача разрешить посетителям сайта покупать товар только в определенные дни. Сам товар должен всегда оставаться в каталоге в любом виде

Вы говорите про этот плагин?
